# Convert XML with . attribute to JSON in java

Tags: java, json, xml, mongodb

I have an `XML` with the attribute `<name.first>`.
I want to convert this `XML` to `JSON` and save it to `MongoDB`.

I am using `org.json.XML` to convert it to `JSONObject` with:

```
XML.toJSONObject(xml)
```

The converted JSON contains the key: `{ ... , name.first : ... }`, which is not supported with `MongoDB`.
Is there a way to serialize the XML converter so that the conversion would output something else like `name_first` ?

Comment: Would it do better to have `{name: { first: ...}}`?

Comment: Yea that could work...  
How can I achieve that?

Comment: As far as I know, you'd have to write it bespoke.  Sorry, not much help.